# which way is the correct way to write these two for loops?

Tags: c

I wish to create two loops with different integer outputs. so I can recognize which one is which. I will have to add many more loops like this into the main function so I'm looking for the easiest solution.

Is this one correct?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX_CARS 1000
main()
{
    double carsTimeheadA[MAX_CARS], carsTimeheadB[MAX_CARS];
    int i,z,n;
    int j,q,a;
    n=100;
    a=1000;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=100; j<a; j++)
            carsTimeheadA[i]=0.0;
        carsTimeheadB[j]=0.0;
    }
}
```

Or this one?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX_CARS 1000
main()
{
    double carsTimeheadA[MAX_CARS], carsTimeheadB[MAX_CARS];
    int i,z,n;
    int j,q,a;
    n=100;
    a=1000;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        carsTimeheadA[i]=0.0;
    }
    for (j=100; j<a; j++)
    {
        carsTimeheadB[j]=0.0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to properly indent your code examples, and you should quickly see a flaw with the first one.

Comment: The second one is correct. But shouldn't `for (j=100; j<a; j++)` be `for (j=n; j<a; j++)` instead? And shouldn't `a=1000;` be `a=MAX_CARS;`?

Comment: Also, that's not how you're supposed to declare [the `main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

Comment: Lastly, think about the elements in `carsTimeheadB` that are *not* initialized. Why aren't you initializing them?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to achieve with the code. Please explain that in more details. It seems you are trying to set the first 100 elements of `carsTimeheadA` and the last 900 elements of `carsTimeheadB`. Is that it ?

Comment: this is just a snippet of a much larger code please ignore the fact carsTimeheadA and B are not initialized. They are in the full code. the code is for two lanes of traffic that have the exact same features as one another. im trying to set the first 100 elements to carsTimeheadA as 1-2-3-4...100 and then set for carsTimeheadB 101-102-103...201. so both have 100 elements each. I think it is as someone mentioned above, the second one but (j=n; j<a; j++). i also think a=200 since i only want 100 cars in lane B and 100 in lane A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want the first 100 element of `carsTimeheadA` to have the values 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 100 and the first 100 element of `carsTimeheadB` to have the values 101, 102, 103, 104, ..., 200

In that case you only need a single loop like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX_CARS 1000
int main()
{
    double carsTimeheadA[MAX_CARS], carsTimeheadB[MAX_CARS];
    int i, n;

    n=100;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        carsTimeheadA[i]= 1.0 + i;
        carsTimeheadB[i]= 101.0 + i;
    }

    // ... more code

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was trying to do thank you user "4386427"

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict between what you code and what your intention is, looking at the indentation. Your loop is, properly indented, as follows:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (j=100; j<a; j++)
        carsTimeheadA[i]=0.0;
    carsTimeheadB[j]=0.0;
}
```

which is a bit nonsense and wrong: You loop 100 times or so over `j` to assign to an element `i`. After the loop, `j` probably points outside the array when you initialize the `j` element.

Do you mean the following?

```
for(i=0; i<MAX_CARS; i++)
{
    carsTimeheadA[i]=0.0;
    carsTimeheadB[i]=0.0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure OP wants to initialize all of the two arrays. However, if that is the purpose OP can simply do: `double carsTimeheadA[MAX_CARS] = {0.0}, carsTimeheadB[MAX_CARS] = {0.0};` No loops needed for that.

Comment: @franklu Please mark the answer that answered your question as the correct answer. Or provide your own answer and mark that as the correct answer. So you'll be able to help others in the future with your question and accepted answer.